# How to insert PHP code into table in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an admin panel for some website, and I want to add the option to publish a new page. I want to build some text editor that will allow the publisher add HTML/PHP code.

I tried to insert text into dababase table and than print that:

```
EOF;
echo "1";
echo <<<EOF
```

But the output is `"EOF; echo "1"; echo <<<EOF"`

How can I add PHP/HTML code into my database table?

Comment: It's usually a very bad idea to do things like that, especially if that comes from a user input, as it could easily affect your server.

Comment: Usually, yes, but I could see doing this in something like an Admin Control Panel, for example if you're making a custom CMS system.

Comment: In this case im building CMS system, and the website will be stored in the site-owner server, so the user in this case can affect only on his own server.. or am im swong?

Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add php/html to the database like a normal, text. After when you retrieve your PHP code, if you want to execute it, you must use [eval](http://ru.php.net/eval) function.

Comment: and don't forget that the storing code in the database is almost always a sign of very bad software design.

Answer (score 2):

It's reversed, it should be

```
echo <<<EOF


echo "1";


EOF;
```